# GetAttr raises AttributeErorr in metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

I'm toying with python to understand how it works, but there is something weird. I'm defining a `__new__` method in my MetaClass, and I expect the fourth argument (which is a dict of attributes of the class-to-be), to contain methods defined in my class-to-be body.

I have this code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


class MyMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs):
        instance = super(MyMetaClass, metacls) #Create instance of super class, which metaclass is type
        print(type(type))
        print(type(type(instance)))
        print(instance.__new__)
        print(type.__new__)
        print(attrs)
        print(getattr(attrs, 'foobar'))
        return super(MyMetaClass, metacls).__new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs)

class TestClass(metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return self
    def foobar(self):
        print(f'My name is {self.name}') 
    def __init__(self, args):
        print(args)
        self.firstname = args['firstname'] if 'firstname' in args else ''
        self.lastname = args['lastname'] if 'lastname' in args else ''
        self.name = f'{self.firstname} {self.lastname}'



data = {'firstname': 'Florian'}
c = TestClass(data)
c.foobar()
```

The output is:

```
<class 'type'>
<class 'type'>
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x10d759e40>
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x10d759e40>
{'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'TestClass', '__get__': <function TestClass.__get__ at 0x10e192b70>, 'foobar': <function TestClass.foobar at 0x10e192bf8>, '__init__': <function TestClass.__init__ at 0x10e192c80>}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 25, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 10, in __new__
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'foobar'
```

So `print(attrs)` in `MyMetaClass.__new__` the result is, as expected :

```
{'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'TestClass', '__get__': <function TestClass.__get__ at 0x7f042b9e6158>, 'foobar': <function TestClass.foobar at 0x7f042b9e61e0>, '__init__': <function TestClass.__init__ at 0x7f042b9e6268>}
```

How you can see, it contains the 'foobar' key.

However, the next line raises `AttributeError : 'dict' object has no attribute 'foobar'`. Why ?

I tried `hasattr(attrs, 'foobar')` which returns false too.

Comment: `foobar` is a dictionary key and not an object attribute. Use key indexing or `dict.get` to retrieved the value correlating with a key. e.g. `attrs['foobar']` or `attrs.get('foobar')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary doesn't expose the keys as attributes. The dictionary will become the namespace for the class being created, but it is *not yet part of a class*. Classes (and their metaclass) have a [`__getattribute__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) that translates attribute access to dictionary lookups, but that's not available on the dictionary object itself.

Just use dictionary subscription access:

```
print(attrs['foobar'])
```

or call `super().__new__()`, store the return value, then look up the attribute on that new class object:

```
class MyMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_class = super(MyMetaClass, metacls).__new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs)
        print(new_class.foobar)
        return new_class
```

Note: `super(MyMetaClass, metacls)` does *not* produce an instance! It returns the `super()` proxy object, attributes on which will be looked up on the metaclass Method Resolution Order (MRO). `super(MyMetaClass, metacls).__new__` is such a lookup, finding the next `__new__` attribute in the metaclass's MRO. In this case that's `type.__new__`, and calling that method produces the actual class object.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer including `__getattribute__`.

Comment: Ok I now understand why `instance.__new__` and `type.__new__` where pointing at the same address. So you're saying that the super() call does not create an instance, and indeed, `hasattr(instance, '__class__')` returns false. But then, what is it ?

Comment: @Florian: `super(instance, cls)` produces a special *proxy object*, where looking up attributes triggers a search along the objects of `type(instance).__mro__` starting at the index after the index of `cls`, to find an attribute of the same name. It also makes sure to bind the object if it's a descriptor (methods are descriptors, see the [descriptor howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)).

Comment: @Florian: `metaclass.__new__` produces a new class object, not instances. You can't create instances until you have a class object, anyway.

Comment: Your explanations made it clearer. If I understood correctly, metaclass.__new__ will build the class object and pass it to __init__ when I try to instantiate the class. Anyway, thank you a lot... :)

Comment: @Florian: `classobject()` will call `type(classobject).__call__`, whose default implementation in turn will call `instance = classobject.__new__()` and if the result of that is an instance of `classobject` or a subclass, will call `instance.__init__()`. So usually you just implement `__init__`. :-)

Comment: @Florian: don't confuse `classobject.__new__` there with `metaclass.__new__` which I helped you with the implementation of in this question. The latter produces class objects, the former instances of the class.

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I had in my mind ! You helped me a lot here. :)

Comment: python doc says that object.__call__ is : "Called when the instance is “called” as a function". However objectclasses are not instances of class type, are they ?

Comment: @Florian what are objectclasses? `object` is the base class for all custom classes in Python. `object` doesn’t actually implement a `__call__` method for those classes to inherit but it’s a convenient way to document that `__call__` can be a method declared on a class. The documentation then states that when you use `instance()` (a call on an instance) results in the `__call__` method being invoked directly on the class. Also see [*special method lookups*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup).

Comment: @Florian: Metaclasses are just very special classes here that happen to produce a class object rather than an instance. So `Class()` is handled by `metaclass.__call__`.

Comment: objectclass is a class I defined, let's say its name is `Class`. So when I call it : `Class()`, I am wondering why the `metaclass.__call__` is called because Class is not an instance of Metaclass. I understand that if I have an instance of Class `c = Class()`, then, `c()` will invoke `Class.__call__` because c is an instance of Class.

Comment: `isinstance(Class, Metaclass)` returns true...Ok, in fact Class is an instance of Metaclass...that's pretty clear now.